# Why does 8086 segment addressing not overflow?

Tags: x86-16, memory-address, memory-segmentation

I know that the 8086 addressing mode is a left shift of the segment register by four bits then add an offset. But will the information of significant bit not be lost after shifting the 16-bit register?

For example, the segment register stores 0x1000, will it not become 0x0000 after shifting four bits to the left?

Comment: Why do you say the segment is shifted?

Comment: In 16-bit real mode, addressing is done by multiplying the value in segment register  by 16 then plus the offset address. @Alejandro

Comment: The processor (original 8086) has 20 address lines (A0 to A19), so when it internally computes a linear address from a segment-offset pair then the internal address is stored in a 20-bit address. Overflow only occurs when overflowing a 20-bit value, such as segmented FFFFh:0010h = (1)0_0000h = 0_0000h. (286 and up had an A20 line (21st address line) which is the reason addresses in the last segments can access up to 64 KiB - 16 B past the first 1 MiB on these machines, as long as A20 isn't masked off.)

Comment: The computer does it for you, don't use `shl` to do it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Address calculation happens with 20-bit math.  Or more on later CPUs.  Not the same width as the inputs.  The CPU doesn't shift *inside* the segment reg!

In CPUs that don't support other modes (like protected mode where the base comes from the GDT), I assume the selected segment register is just hard-wired to bits [20:4] of an adder in the AGU, so the "shift" is just built-in to the wiring.  Not like when you run a shift instruction and the result goes back into the destination.

(Actual 8086 didn't have an AGU separate from its ALU, so presumably that's what happens when using that block of logic to do address math instead of 16-bit normal integer math.  It also supports a `mul` instruction which produces a 32-bit product, that has to get split across DX:AX when it's done, but internally the ALU has to shift and add numbers across 16-bit boundaries for multiply to work.)